# Python: Upload file to ftp issue

Tags: python, upload, ftp

In my program, I just use the for loop for upload the created file to an ftp server.
I get upload success but empty content. The strangest thing is that when I hard code the file name then the content is there. But when I use the parameter name for the upload function then I just get the empty file.

Here is the uploading code.
`section_number` is the for loop key.

```
 if group == 1:
        title_str = 'pri'
    elif group == 2:
        title_str = 'sec'
    else:
        title_str = 'all'
    filename = '%s_section_s%d.json'%(title_str,section_number)
    with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:        
        json.dump(dictData, outfile)
    ftp.ftpUpload(filename, "dataFile/")

def ftpUpload(filename, filePath):
    ftp = ftplib.FTP('203.xx.x.xxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxxx')
    ftp.cwd(filePath) #changing to /pub/unix    
    '''filename = 'sec_section_s5.json';''' 
    ftp.storlines("STOR %s"%(filename), open(filename, 'rb'))
    files = ftp.dir()
    ftp.close()
```

Comment: can you give examples of your file names?

Comment: never give your passwords credintails like that ..

Comment: Oh.... Thanks for edited. i am too nervous right now. =[